# How to initiate one jquery plugin in another jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

i'm beginner to jQuery plugins, i need to initiate one plugin in another plugin. can we do this?

if yes , please post with suitable example.

Comment: "i need to initiate one plugin in another plugin" What do you mean by 'initiate in'? Any practical sample?

Comment: initiate means call, i need to call one plugin in other plugin

Comment: So why accepting answer which has nothing to do with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean calling another plugin inside your own plugin? Just call it using this statement:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

      this.callAnotherPlugin()

  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Funny enough, OP accepted other answer which is not wrong but doesn't fit with question...

Answer (score 0):

Just import plugins in the order of their use:

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='plugin1.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='plugin2.js'></script>
```